# Java XPath query does not get text in node?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

When I run the following code, I get the output `Left:` instead of `Left: 16`.

```
    // Retrieve DOM from XML file
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    Document dom = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom = db.parse("config");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    try {
        String left = (String) xPath.evaluate(
                "/settings/boundaries[0]/left[0]", dom,
                XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println("Left: " + left);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the XML file

```
<settings>
    <boundaries>
        <left>16</left>
        <right>301</right>
        <bottom>370</bottom>
        <top>171</top>
    </boundaries>
</settings>
```

**EDIT:** Based on the answers, this should work, but it doesn't:

```
// Retrieve DOM from XML file
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    Document dom = null;
    try {
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom = db.parse("config");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    try {
        String left = (String) xPath.evaluate(
                "/settings/boundaries[0]/left[0]/text()", dom,
                XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println("Left: " + left);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also note that this code,

```
Element el = (Element) dom.getDocumentElement()
            .getElementsByTagName("boundaries").item(0);

System.out.println(el.getElementsByTagName("left").item(0));
```

Prints `[left: null]`

Comment: Please work on writing more relevant/focused titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nodes are indexed starting at 1. Try `/settings/boundaries[1]/left[1]`

Comment: That is incredibly stupid, but thank you. (I also had to add /text() to the expression).

Comment: I wish it was consistent through-out all programming too (Zero-based indexing).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the toString() definition of a node. That is not documented to do anything especially. If you want the node name use XPathConstants.NODE and use the node apis, or if you want the value append .text() to your xpath string in the evaluate call.

Comment: Would my expression look like this: "/settings/boundaries[0]/left[0]/text()"?

Answer (score 2):

As I've used it you gotta add the /text() at the end to retrieve the data on that node

> /settings/boundaries[0]/left[0]/text()

Comment: Looks like this was *half* of the solution.